# Problem displaying two images inside a cell in HTML table

Tags: html, css, styles

I am working with an html table that I would like in one of your cells to be able to show two images, the problem I have at the moment is that both images are together by the styles that apply to them so far, as I can add a space in the middle of both?

```css
.text-content {
  text-align: justify;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10pt;
}

.text-title {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12pt;
  color: #000;
}

.thubnail img {
  float: left;
  max-width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td width="8%">Item</td>
        <td width="8%">Quantity</td>
        <td width="10%">Size</td>
        <td width="50%">Description</td>
        <td width="10%">P/U</td>
        <td width="14%">Total ($.)</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td width="8%" rowspan="2" class="text-content">1</td>
        <td width="8%" rowspan="2" class="text-content">3</td>
        <td width="10%" rowspan="2" class="text-content">12 x 6</td>
        <td width="50%" class="text-title">test description</td>
        <td width="10%" rowspan="2" class="text-content">2000</td>
        <td width="14%" rowspan="2" class="text-content">6000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" class="text-content">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit dignissim, volutpat sapien tellus cubilia mollis sollicitudin nibh nisi curabitur, nullam semper mi duis erat pellentesque nunc. Quis cursus vulputate auctor habitant quisque nibh facilisi vivamus rutrum cubilia, cras dignissim suspendisse vel condimentum lectus cum mauris integer, aenean luctus augue vitae vestibulum quam ac purus parturient.
          <div class="thubnail">
<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/77020/desmond.jpg" alt="Desmond">
          </div>
          <div class="thubnail">
<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/77020/desmond.jpg" alt="Desmond">
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using flexbox can be a solution.

```css
.text-content {
  text-align: justify;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10pt;
}

.text-title {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12pt;
  color: #000;
}

.thubnail {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.thubnail img {
  flex: 0 1 49%;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td width="8%">Item</td>
      <td width="8%">Quantity</td>
      <td width="10%">Size</td>
      <td width="50%">Description</td>
      <td width="10%">P/U</td>
      <td width="14%">Total ($.)</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="8%" rowspan="2" class="text-content">1</td>
      <td width="8%" rowspan="2" class="text-content">3</td>
      <td width="10%" rowspan="2" class="text-content">12 x 6</td>
      <td width="50%" class="text-title">test description</td>
      <td width="10%" rowspan="2" class="text-content">2000</td>
      <td width="14%" rowspan="2" class="text-content">6000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" class="text-content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit dignissim, volutpat sapien tellus cubilia mollis sollicitudin nibh nisi curabitur, nullam semper mi duis erat pellentesque nunc. Quis cursus vulputate auctor habitant quisque nibh facilisi vivamus
        rutrum cubilia, cras dignissim suspendisse vel condimentum lectus cum mauris integer, aenean luctus augue vitae vestibulum quam ac purus parturient.
        <div class="thubnail">
          <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/77020/desmond.jpg" alt="Desmond">
          <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/77020/desmond.jpg" alt="Desmond">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but it is a very big separation, is there any way that it is minimal?

Comment: big separation between 2 images?